# How to relate inner properties with first-level ones of an object type typed using an index signature?

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have the following object type:

```
type Digit = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9;

type Obj = { 
    [K in "prop_a" | "prop_b" | "prop_c"]: {
        [P in `${K}${Digit}`]: unknown;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.0-dev.20221228#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgczsKBeKAGKAfKBGHKAJkIGZCAWQgVkIDZCB2QgDkIE4BuAKG9EigB5AEYArNFADeUblDlQA2gGkocAHZQARGABOAezAB9AIabC2-UeFncFg4YDGmgLoAuKbPleFABVUaAAwASSSUAXxD4JGAwgLcoAFc1AGs1PQB3NR4vMO4woA)

By iterating on `"prop_a" | "prop_b" | "prop_c"` with `K` we can refer directly to each constituent of the union to impose the `K-th` prop as a prefix of each inner property of the corresponding sub-object.

The question is: is it possible to get a similar result when the properties of the first level are not known? If yes, how?

A trivial but incorrect attempt is the following:

```
type Digit = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9;

type Obj = { 
    [K in string]: {
        [P in `${K}${Digit}`]: unknown;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.0-dev.20221228#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgczsKBeKAGKAfKBGHKAJkIGZCAWQgVkIDZCB2QgDkIE4BuAKG9EigB5AEYArNFADeUblDlQA2gGkocAHZQAzsABO6hAF0AXFNnzzCgAqqNAAwAkkpQF9H8JMGe3jUAK5qAazUAewB3NR5zZ25o7gATCABjABsAQx1oROC1bShgsRMRUR5uAHpSrQALYN9kuKgIHR1gnTzfFGEk1N9NaGBK6DAMgDM4AA8oIYgANzgazShgYMWBqDjEZFUFkJQAIlDK1OAZxt3ufNEAOgOjk51L5AB9TWrauMfG5p0MEvKoUR6KH60GGwWSyTC+iqNTqUE6UFSiUSEDAx3qcGGKxBcB0uWSJ2SUACEBAWyg+0Ox2mp3OYmulLu9Nu1O+PAuTKpjQ5dzwbLpN059wFdyIfKuwpZ3JZpDFUq5EsaFFlCqFDJZ1GVavlWp0dE1zO1Bp0jH1grlOhYpsZKq4QA)

Because the prefix of an inner property is not constrained to the name of the corresponding key on the first level:

```
declare const obj: Obj;

// should error out because the prefix previous to the digit is not "whatever"
obj.whatever.it_should_error0;

// just the following should be accepted if the first level key is "whatever"
obj.whatever.whatever0;
obj.whatever.whatever1;
obj.whatever.whatever2;
obj.whatever.whatever3;
obj.whatever.whatever4;
obj.whatever.whatever5;
obj.whatever.whatever6;
obj.whatever.whatever7;
obj.whatever.whatever8;
obj.whatever.whatever9;
```

Comment: No, there is no specific type in TypeScript that works this way.  You could make a generic constraint that depends on the set of top-level keys.  But can you describe the use case?  Is `obj` a proxy or something?  And if so, you'll probably be happier with using a method instead of a proxied property, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9ba1m).

Comment: No, `Obj` its just a type for dynamic data that respect a similar characteristic. Of course first level access should return `undefined` as well for better safety, I've just simplified a bit the type. The set of keys is not known at compile time, so I cannot use the generic costraint. @jcalz

Comment: I wasn't able to find a proper way as well, but my knowledge is limited so I tried to ask

Comment: @jcalz that solution, the one that exploits a getter, is quite interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no specific type in TypeScript that works this way.  [Mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `string` doesn't behave the way you want; it results in a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) that does not keep track of the particular key.  Support for a type like you are describing was explicitly declined in [microsoft/TypeScript#22509](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22509), so I don't think this will be possible in the foreseeable future.

You could possibly write `Obj` as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) constraint:

```
type Obj<K extends string> = { [P in K]: { [Q in `${P}${Digit}`]: unknown } };
declare const obj: Obj<"whatever" | "otherThing">;
obj.whatever.whatever0 // okay
obj.whatever.it_should_error0; // error
```

You may not know the full key set at compile time, but if you know *any* keys you should be able to represent it this way (`Obj<KnownKeys | UnknownKeys>` can be safely widened/upcast to `Obj<KnownKeys>`, just like `{foo: string, bar: number}` can be safely widened to `{foo: string}`).

Otherwise the only approach I can think of which approximates what you're describing would be to refactor to use amethod instead of property access:

```
interface Obj {
    get<K extends string>(k: K): { [P in `${K}${Digit}`]: unknown };
}
declare const obj: Obj;
const objWhatever = obj.get("whatever");
objWhatever.whatever0; // okay
objWhatever.it_should_error0; // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIBECWBzRpYF5YAZYB9YBGfWAJhIGYSAWEgVhIDYSB2EgDhIE4BuEAOwCGAW2gBnSIIDGcAMIB7fmNAAnQYn7oA3sFh7YEGLADyAIwBWAHgDSsaAA9Q0fgBMxsZSo3IAfJlhasADaAAqwGrDWALoAXAHBAIrh-LAABgAkWiEAvplIqKDZqbGwAK78ANb88gDuKdmw2Xz6sC7QUgA2gipwUorKsPIWcWZWAEQ1ABaCTgBu0CpjJGPyoJMLACqT3mM+zfpD5gB0UzPQ8yon03MLuAD0d4MVguC6BxZXZxdHaAD6YpN5KUOi5fgsVPIVNgeLAHnYVBCVMBsgIROJJDJYAAlaAAM2koEhATeeg0ThU+Mxo2JLRayGgoBsdkczjcHlU3h8AAoKnFrABKOKBULJNKZay5LT5NBFErlKq1er7PQolptTrdXr9dCHEYWZWwPpKHUWADq13OC38hyO9NAXImFouY35BsO5q+C0+NyhMLh8merxa7qdXr+AKBILBCMh0Nhj3BkJJsGRQA)